# Spring xml constructor injection of JPA entity manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring in a standalone desktop application along with JPA and Hibernate. So what i need is a global entity manager, provided by spring. The thing is, i use the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and constructor injection, because i prefer my classes to be totally free of any framework.

So a bean in my ApplicationContext.xml basically looks like this:

```
<bean id="bookingDAO" class="dk.gokartland.booking.dao.BookingDAO">
    <constructor-arg name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

So i do the actual wiring myself.

So what i've done until now is pass the EntityManagerFactory to my DAOs, but this doesn't really work when i close it manually. So i would like to pass the same EntityManager around.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa

The LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean sounds like what i need, but i do not know how to map it through the applicationContext.xml.

My current JPA configuration looks like:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="dk.gokartland.booking.domain"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{database['jdbc.url']}"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{database['jdbc.username']}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{database['jdbc.password']}"/>
</bean>
```

Now somehow i need to be able to to something like this:

```
<bean id="bookingDAO" class="dk.gokartland.booking.dao.BookingDAO">
    <constructor-arg name="entityManager" ref="entityManager"/>
</bean>
```

Hope someone has a simple solution :)

Comment: Have you tried 

` <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit"/>
   </bean>`

`<bean id="bookingDAO" class="dk.gokartland.booking.dao.BookingDAO">
    <constructor-arg name="entityManager" ref="myEmf"/>
</bean>`

Comment: But i dont want to inject the factory, i want to inject a shared/singleton entitymanager that is managed through spring? :-)

Comment: Spring does not support constructor injection of EntityManager, see [SPR-10443](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10443) which is scheduled for Spring 5.0.